# Reinforce Learning for environment which cannot be affected by agent

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The model of RL is defined as `P^a_ss'`, the action space is continuous. In order to make the agent knows that the env would behave it own ways regardless what the agent does, what would I do?

It is also desirable to learn the state transition of the env, would RL at all be suffice for the job? If yes, the env has only one continuous variable `x_0` in in observation space, and a numberous of hidden factors `x_1, x_2, ...` that affect `x_0`; should `x_1, x_2, ...` be in the observation space too? If no, what would I do next beside RNN?